# Can a roaming pokemon appear in the Battle Zone?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

Where exactly can roaming pokemon appear? Is it anywhere where there is tall grass?

I am specifically wondering about Mesprit and the Battle Zone, in Pokemon Brilliant Diamond: Routes 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, and 230.

None of the wikis on the Internet (Bulbapedia, serebii, etc) for these routes, or any other route where I know a roaming pokemon can appear, list the roaming pokemon on those pages. The Roaming Pokemon pages don't list the possible locations for them.

The closest I can find is [this tweet](https://twitter.com/MrCheeze_/status/1264318789388324865) showing some of the code.

Comment: That tweet is for a different game, though.

Comment: @pinckerman I didn't see which game it was from, but the logic seems to be relatively similar to BDSP